# nuxt auth v5 not setting loggedin when use login & logout

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

when user logging in, the `this.$auth.$state.loggedIn` value stay `false`
and when reload the page it's work

also when user logging out, the `this.$auth.$state.loggedIn` value stay `true`
and when reload the page it's work

this is my `nuxt.config.js`:

```
auth: {
    rewriteRedirects: false,
    redirect: {
      login: '/login',
      logout: '/',
      callback: false,
      home: false
    },
    strategies: {
      local: {
        token: {
          property: 'auth_token',
          global: true,
          required: true,
          type: 'Bearer',
          maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 12 * 70
        },
        user: {
          property: false
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: '/v1/token/login/', method: 'post' },
          logout: false,
          user: { url: '/v1/user', method: 'get' }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

and login function:

```
const login = await this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
              data: userData
            }).catch((err) => {
              if (!err.response) { return }
              console.log(err)

              switch (err.response.status) {
                case 403:
                  this.error = 'Incorrect username/password'
                  break
                case 401:
                  this.error = 'Incorrect username/password'
                  break
                case 417:
                  this.error = 'Unauthorized.'
                  break
                default:
                  this.error = 'Something Wrong Happend'
                  break
              }
            })
```

and logout function:

```
async onLogout () {
      await this.$auth.logout()
      this.$nuxt.$router.push('/')
    }
```

nuxt versiom: "^2.15.3"
@nuxtjs/auth-next versiom: "5.0.0-1648802546.c9880dc"

Comment: After the login, did you set the user? https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/auth#setuseruser This is what will be passing the state of `loggedIn`to `true`.

Comment: yes i do, but not work, also i write `this.$auth.$storage.setUniversal('loggedIn', true)` but not work

Comment: after logging in, i check the storage in nuxt auth `Universal Storage`, `Cookies`, `Local Storage` are true, but `Local State` stay false

Comment: when i clear localstorage and cookies then reload page, it's work when logging in, and  `this.$auth.$state.loggedIn` is true, and when logging out also work, `this.$auth.$state.loggedIn' is false, but after logout when i try to logging in the problem back `this.$auth.$state.loggedIn` is false :(

Comment: I'm not sure that `setUniversal` is the solution here since you're forcing it rather than letting the module setting it to `true` itself. You should use a Cookie for the maximum security with a JWT. So...you can successfully login + logout but it doesn't work if you try to login again? Hm, strange. Did you checked your Vue devtools to try to understand what is happening exactly?

Comment: i saw devtools, when i use `setUser` i insert only username, and it logging in work without problem, and in state show only username, but when i reload page give me more data coming from endpoint user `user: { url: '/v1/user', method: 'get' }`, after this reload (login/logout) not work correctly

Comment: after reload page, setting auth in (login/logout) stoped! `this.$auth.$state` not change, but when i see vuex, localstorage, cookies it's changed already,

Comment: i think i now where is the problem, i use SRR mode, after reload page, the data on the server side does not change, while the data on the client side does.